# Yii2 Kartik Extension File Not Found

Tags: php, yii, yii2, widget, yii-extensions

I'm new to `Yii` and I have installed the Kartik export extension. When I click on export in any format, I get the following error:

> File not found
>
> Firefox can't find the file at
>   http://localhost/basic/web/index.php?r=industrial/index&page=1.
>
> Check the file name for capitalization or other typing errors. Check
>   to see if the file was moved, renamed or deleted.

When I run this path mentioned, the page opens normally. Am I missing something here?

Please check my code:

IndustrialController.php:

```
<?php 

namespace app\controllers; 
use yii\web\Controller; 
use yii\data\Pagination; 
use app\models\industrial; 
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider; class IndustrialController extends Controller {

public function actionIndex()
{
      $query = industrial::find();
    $pagination = new Pagination([
        'defaultPageSize' => 20,
        'totalCount' => $query->count(),
    ]);

    $industrials = $query->orderBy('Company_Name')
        ->offset($pagination->offset)
        ->limit($pagination->limit)
        ->all();


     $dataProvider=new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => industrial::find(),
'pagination'=>['pageSize'=>20],
    ]);

    //return $this->render('index', ['dataProvider'=>$dataProvider]);
             return $this->render('index', [
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'industrials' => $industrials,
        'pagination' => $pagination,
    ]);
}
}
```

Views/industrial/index.php:

```
 <?php 


use yii\helpers\Html; 
use kartik\export\ExportMenu; 
use kartik\grid\GridView; 
use yii\widgets\LinkPager; 

$gridColumns = [ ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

'Company_Name',
'Category',
'Phone',
'EMail',
];
?>



<?= ExportMenu::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'columns' => $gridColumns,
'fontAwesome' => true,
'dropdownOptions' => [
'label' => 'Export All',
'class' => 'btn btn-default'
]
]) ?>
<?= GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'columns' => $gridColumns,
'export' => [
'fontAwesome' => true,
]
]); ?>
```

What is the action I need to add to the controller to download the extracted file?

Comment: Try with this code... It may work bt i'm nt sure. 
     'target' => ExportMenu::TARGET_BLANK

Comment: you are totally overdoing everything you have the `search` model for this purpose and you should use the `search()` function to query and paginate the results and avoid such problems as you are facing.